# Using gamesparks typescript/javascript libraries in flutter

Tags: javascript, dart, flutter, gamesparks

I am planning to build a simple turn based multiplayer using gamesparks for the backend. I have considered flutter/dart and react native for the app development. There is a javascript gamesparks [SDK](https://docs.gamesparks.com/sdk-center/javascript.html) which uses sockets for network IO. Can this library be safely used in flutter/dart using js [package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/js)? I plan to proceed with react native if it cannot be used.